# What is the term for the result of an Euler vector?

Tags: vectors, vectorization

An Euler 'vector' is not a vector, because it has direction, but no magnitude. It is also not a scalar. So, what is an Euler vector? A direction?

Comment: Is it not a unit vector? (i.e., its magnitude is 1?)

Comment: @Theophile, I thought it's length was simply 'arbitrary', but for all intents and purposes, it may as well be 1.

Comment: Well, if the length doesn't matter, then it's just a vector. If the length is 1 (which I believe is the case), then it's a unit vector. Points on the projective plane also somewhat fit your description: they are of the form $\mathbf x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, where not all the $x_i$ are zero, and the points $\lambda \mathbf x$, for any $\lambda \neq 0$, are considered identical. (So $(1,0) = (2,0) = (-1,0)$, for example; this is the direction in $\mathbb R^2$ through the $x$-axis.)